# How to setting wfastcgi make flask server run in Production mode?

Tags: python, flask, wfastcgi

I am using wfastcgi intergrate flask server to IIS, even when I setting environment variable FLASK_CONFIG=production in system , the flask server always run in development mode, any suggustion?

Comment: Could you show the relevant code please? How do you verify that the mode is development? How do you set your own config?
Maybe used modules override your own config?

Comment: @Emil I use different config params, like db url, connect different db, can show me.